# How to use internal/external docker network in same time?

Tags: php, docker, docker-network, docker-desktop

I currently have two docker-composes, and a shared database. To share my DB, I made a network that I call from the outside, but when I put this "external" parameter, my network is no longer available internally, how to use a network both internally and externally?

docker-compose 1 :

```
networks:
  my-target-network:
    external:
      name: my-target-network
...
...
I use external network with next code
```

docker-compose 2 :

```
networks:
   my-target-network:
    name: my-target-network
...
... 
I use my network here with internal container
```

When I activate the external option, my network becomes accessible from the outside, but becomes inaccessible internally, why?

Comment: Do you have a more complete example of what you mean by "internally" and "externally", and the specific container setup where networking stops working?  Can you have a separate database for each Compose setup rather than trying to share one database between applications?

Comment: I have no choice, I have to share a database internally, and externally for my technical specifications. Internal would mean reaching a container inside the docker-compose, and external would mean reaching a container outside, in another container on another docker-compose (but on the same host docker machine).